# solve system of ODEs with read in external forcing

Tags: julia, ode, differentialequations.jl

In Julia, I want to solve a system of ODEs with external forcings `g1(t), g2(t)` like

```
dx1(t) / dt = f1(x1, t) + g1(t)
dx2(t) / dt = f2(x1, x2, t) + g2(t)
```

with the forcings read in from a file.

I am using this study to learn Julia and the package DifferentialEquations, but I am having difficulties finding the correct approach.

I could imagine that using a `callback` could work, but that seems pretty cumbersome.

Do you have an idea of how to implement such an external forcing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use functions inside of the integration function. So you can use something like [Interpolations.jl](https://github.com/JuliaMath/Interpolations.jl) to build an interpolating polynomial from the data in your file, and then do something like:

```
g1 = interpolate(data1, options...)
g2 = interpolate(data2, options...)
p = (g1,g2) # Localize these as parameters to the model

function f(du,u,p,t)
g1,g2 = p
  du[1] = ... + g1[t] # Interpolations.jl interpolates via []
  du[2] = ... + g2[t]
end
# Define u0 and tspan
ODEProblem(f,u0,tspan,p)
```

Comment: It's hard to know without seeing what you're trying to do. My guess would be you may need to re-write the data into a different format: maybe it only wants to interpolate vectors. We can discuss this in more detail in the [Gitter channel](https://gitter.im/JuliaLang/julia) the [Julia Slack](https://slackinvite.julialang.org/), or the [Julia Discourse](https://discourse.julialang.org/). These avenues are better for long discussions, whereas StackOverflow is just simple question->answer.

Comment: OK, thanks, I had some problems with reloading the new code. I'll have to play around a bit more and in case I'll stumble upon new problems, I'll had over to the discussion groups. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for a nice question and nice answer by @Chris Rackauckas.
Below a complete reproducible example of such a problem. Note that Interpolations.jl has changed the indexing to `g1(t)`.

```
using Interpolations
using DifferentialEquations
using Plots

time_forcing = -1.:9.
data_forcing = [1,0,0,1,1,0,2,0,1, 0, 1]
g1_cst = interpolate((time_forcing, ), data_forcing, Gridded(Constant()))
g1_lin = scale(interpolate(data_forcing, BSpline(Linear())), time_forcing)

p_cst = (g1_cst) # Localize these as parameters to the model
p_lin = (g1_lin) # Localize these as parameters to the model


function f(du,u,p,t)
  g1 = p
  du[1] = -0.5 + g1(t) # Interpolations.jl interpolates via ()
end

# Define u0 and tspan
u0 = [0.]
tspan = (-1.,9.) # Note, that we would need to extrapolate beyond 
ode_cst = ODEProblem(f,u0,tspan,p_cst)
ode_lin = ODEProblem(f,u0,tspan,p_lin)

# Solve and plot
sol_cst = solve(ode_cst)
sol_lin = solve(ode_lin)

# Plot
time_dense = -1.:0.1:9.
scatter(time_forcing, data_forcing,   label = "discrete forcing")
plot!(time_dense, g1_cst(time_dense), label = "forcing1",  line = (:dot,   :red))
plot!(sol_cst,                        label = "solution1", line = (:solid, :red))
plot!(time_dense, g1_lin(time_dense), label = "forcing2",  line = (:dot,   :blue))
plot!(sol_lin,                        label = "solution2", line = (:solid, :blue))
```

[image]