# TypeError in Julia/Turing when sampling for a forced differential equation

Tags: julia, bayesian, differential-equations, automatic-differentiation, differentialequations.jl

I am new to Julia and Turing and am trying to fit a forced 0-D box ODE to data, but I get type error when doing sampling.

Following this page ([solve system of ODEs with read in external forcing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49428939/solve-system-of-odes-with-read-in-external-forcing)), I added an interpolation handle of the forcing as a parameter of the ODE, and the ODE solver runs without problems.

When I combine the forced ODE with Turing, following https://turing.ml/dev/tutorials/10-bayesian-differential-equations/, I get a type error during HMC's gradient calculation, quoting ”TypeError: in typeassert, expected Float64, got a value of type ForwardDiff.Dual{Nothing, Float64, 3}”.

Below are my codes that should reproduce the error I got.

I appreciate any help, Thanks.

Below are my codes:

```
    using Interpolations, DifferentialEquations, Plots, Turing, LinearAlgebra

    # Define ODE
    function f(du,u,p,t)
          α, β, F = p
          du[1] = α * u[1] + β * F(t) # Interpolations.jl interpolates via ()
    end

    # Define initial value problem
    begin
        # Define forcing 
        time_forcing = -1.:9.
        data_forcing = [10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0, 0]
        F = Interpolations.scale(interpolate(data_forcing, BSpline(Linear())), time_forcing)
        α = -0.5
        β = 1
        p_lin = (α, β, F) 

        # Define u0 and tspan
        u0 = [0.]
        tspan = (-1.,9.) # Note, that we would need to extrapolate beyond 
        ode_lin = ODEProblem(f,u0,tspan,p_lin)
    end

    # Generate data
    sol  = solve(ode_lin, Tsit5(); saveat=1)
    data = Array(sol) + 0.2 * randn(size(Array(sol)))

    @model function fit_simple_box(data, F, ode_lin)
        # Prior distributions.
        σ ~ InverseGamma(2, 3)
        α ~ Normal(0, 3)
        β ~ Normal(0, 3)

        # Simulate Lotka-Volterra model. 
        p = (α, β, F)
        predicted = solve(ode_lin, Tsit5(); p=p, saveat=1)

        # Observations.
        for i in 1:length(predicted)
            data[i] ~ Normal(predicted[i][1], σ^2)
        end

        return nothing
    end

    model = fit_simple_box(data, F, ode_lin)
    chain = sample(model, NUTS(0.65), MCMCSerial(), 1000, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Chris Rackauckas,
changing

```
predicted = solve(ode_lin, Tsit5(); p=p, saveat=1)
```

to

```
predicted = solve(ode_lin, Tsit5(); p=p, saveat=1, u0 = typeof(α).(ode_lin.u0))
```

promotes u0 to the correct type and solves the problem.
Ref: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/typeerror-in-julia-turing-when-sampling-for-a-forced-differential-equation/82937/2

Comment: Yes, and the next version of DiffEqBase (v6.91?) will do this automatically, https://github.com/SciML/DiffEqBase.jl/pull/773, so in the future this won't be necessary.